# create multiple columns with df.apply that uses multi return function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I am creating a new column with df.apply and a function and would like to use the same function to create another column in the dataframe. The function returns several values from which I'm selecting one successfully. To avoid new calculation I would like to get two return outputs and create two columns in the dataframe.

```
df_RoadSegments["NewTime"] = df_RoadSegments.apply(lambda x: getrouteinfo(x["OriginCoordinates"], x["DestCoordinates"])[8], axis=1)
```

but I would like to have something like below, is it possible?

```
df_RoadSegments["NewTime"]["link"] = df_RoadSegments.apply(lambda x: getrouteinfo(x["OriginCoordinates"], x["DestCoordinates"])[8][9], axis=1)
```

Comment: `df_RoadSegments[["NewTime","link"]] = ...`

Comment: I've tried this `df_RoadSegments[["NewTime","link"]] = df_RoadSegments.apply(lambda x: getrouteinfo(x["OriginCoordinates"], x["DestCoordinates"])[8][9], axis=1)` and got error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I've changed as suggested and now this is the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: You need to add `result_type='expand'` to the apply

Comment: I've included the `results_type="expand"` and gives the same `ValueError`

Comment: You'll need to give more info about what `getrouteinfo` returns then...

Comment: Sorry, `[8][9]` should actually be `[8:10]`. Brain fade...

Comment: Nice, it works now! Many thanks

Comment: Good to hear. Sorry about the original stuff-up time waste...